# Purge / Delete multiple items from a DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In order to maintain the size of a Dynamodb acceptable.
I need to have a triggerable and periodic way of purging the database.
It seems that Amazon DynamoDB supports a BatchWriteItem action for deleting multiple items at the same time.
What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the built-in TTL feature:

> Time to Live (TTL) for Amazon DynamoDB lets you define when items in a
>   table expire so that they can be automatically deleted from the
>   database. With TTL enabled on a table, you can set a timestamp for
>   deletion on a per-item basis, allowing you to limit storage usage to
>   only those records that are relevant.
>
> TTL is useful if you have continuously accumulating data that loses
>   relevance after a specific time period (for example, session data,
>   event logs, usage patterns, and other temporary data). If you have
>   sensitive data that must be retained only for a certain amount of time
>   according to contractual or regulatory obligations, TTL helps you
>   ensure that it is removed promptly and as scheduled.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html